# Breaking for/if loops in HTML within Django

Tags: html, django, for-loop

I am using HTML Templates in Django and searching through a list of objects. If one of them exists, I want to print something out. However, once that is printed. I do not want to print any more, even if more exist. (i.e. if the condition is met on one of the objects I want to print out the same thing I would if the condition is met on 100 of the objects)

Here's what I have so far:

```
                {% for object in objects %}
                {% if object.attr1 == true %}
                Placeholder
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

If object.attr1 is true for any of the objects I want to print placeholder. But I only want to do it once. Difficulties within Django models have made it so that using this type of for loop is one of my only solutions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
   model = YourModel.objects.filter(attr1=true).all()
   return render(request, "your_template.html", {"objects": model})
```

Comment: I need to handle it inside of HTML because this is actually all inside a much larger for loop that runs over some other set of elements. My models are very complicated and I'm trying to see if there's a way to handle this in HTML.

Comment: maybe you're using Django Forms ?

Comment: hi, if you are using django.forms you can use a statement like this {% if form.label == "Name Label"%}

Comment: what would “Name Label” be here?

Comment: okay, you using for loop from model or django.forms ?

Comment: its from a model, but the tough part is that i need to access the information from the same model a bunch of different times throughout my website because the objects from that model have a relationship with different objects that I create elements on my website for. complicated I know